# What else can I do with Visual Studio's Devices?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, embedded, windows-ce, device

I develop code for embedded devices with Visual Studio 2008 (WinCE 6), and I can connect to the device using the "Devices" tab.  I know that I can further do things like Remote File Viewer and Remote Heap Viewer, but what else can I do with this connection?

I was hoping to be able to run commands like "del \usb*" or something like that to automate things before I deploy my code to the device for debugging.

I Googled, and I think the answer is "no, there's nothing else you can do", and if so, anyone have workaround for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the Remote Tools Framework 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee503727(v=winembedded.60).aspx
to develop your own tools or use RAPI over ActiveSync (may not work if your device does not support AS) to invoke functions from DLLs on the remote device.